# SaltStack: Requisite declaration file /etc/ssh/sshd_config in SLS sshd is not formed as a single key dictionary

Tags: ssh, salt-stack

I get this error message:

> Requisite declaration file /etc/ssh/sshd_config in SLS monitoring.sshd is not formed as a single key dictionary

Here the sls file:

```
sshd:
  service.running:
    - watch:
      - file /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - repl: PermitUserEnvironment yes
    - pattern: ^.*PermitUserEnvironment.*$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the sls file. After adding a `:` between `file` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` it worked.

Here is the working sls file:

```
sshd:
  service.running:
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - repl: PermitUserEnvironment yes
    - pattern: ^.*PermitUserEnvironment.*$
```

Comment: Yaml lint should give you some idea when something went wrongs .
http://www.yamllint.com/